# DocumentsContract's buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri)); returns parent Uri tree

Tags: android, uri

I am trying to use DocumentsContract to traverse a directory recursively using the following method.

```
    void traverseDirectoryEntries(Uri rootUri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activityMain.getContentResolver();
        Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                rootUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(rootUri));
        List<Uri> dirNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        dirNodes.add(childrenUri);
        while (!dirNodes.isEmpty()) {
            childrenUri = dirNodes.remove(0); // get the item from top
            try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, new String[]{
                            DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                            DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                            DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE},
                    null, null, null)) {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        final String docId = cursor.getString(0);
                        final String name = cursor.getString(1);
                        final String mime = cursor.getString(2);
                        if (isDirectory(mime)) {
                            final Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                                    rootUri, docId);
                            traverseDirectoryEntries(newNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Util method to check if the mime type is a directory
    private static boolean isDirectory(String mimeType) {
        return DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR.equals(mimeType);
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. It goes through the same root directory over and over despite the directory passed in being a child of the root. The line `final Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId);` returns a Uri with the child directory attached at the end. That works fine. The problem is the follwing line: `Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(rootUri));` where rootUri is the newNode. I get the same childrenUri; the one I got from rootUri. Is this a bug? Did I make a mistake? Is the docId wrong? I tried `getDocumentId(rootUri)`, but that throws an error because the id it returns is not a tree. It is almost like `getTreeDocumentId(rootUri)` is returning what `getRootId(rootUri)` should be returning. Is there a way to fix this?

The rootUri was obtained via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. I am running this on Android Pie. I left some code out where I am building a tree structure from the data.

Comment: Please start your post telling/showing how you obtained the root uri.

Comment: Please tell which Android version on used device.

Comment: Why this construction with a list? You add one item only and then remove it. You cannot even use the list revursivly.

Comment: Why are you making so many variables final?

Comment: I copied the code and didn't delete the final variables. Also, I am building a tree structure with this method; I left that code out since it uses a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are abusing this well known `void traverseDirectoryEntries(Uri rootUri)` function.

You think it is recursive but it is not.

Remove the recursive call and instead add 'newNode' to the list.

```
// traverseDirectoryEntries(newNode);

dirNodes.add(newNode);
```

Then you make use of the list.

Then original code is restored.

Who changed it without telling so?

Of course you can adapt this function to make it recursiv.

Nice exercise ;-).